# Defining an array with no initial size?

Tags: c++

I have a question about declaring arrays as of an unknown size I was under the impression that syntax like this is legal:
char [] word
But when I go to compile it isn't correct. I'm doing a school project on postfix notation and I do exactly known the size of the equation and I always thought that the above syntax is legal and I swear I have used it? Do you have to use the new keyword to allocate memory for an array of unkown size?

Comment: It's a valid but incomplete type if that's what you mean. Implying you can't create such a thing, but it's not a syntax error (among other things)

Comment: Use std::vector instead

Comment: Need more information on the context. For example, valid as a function parameter. Also valid in C as the last member of a structure (Search term: Flexible Array Member), but not in C++. This trick is allowed by extension in C++ by some compilers, likely to compile C code. Because it's a non-standard extension, don't expect it to be there in all compilers or to behave the same in the compilers that do support it.

Comment: perhaps your teacher wants you to read about containers (`std::vector`) or about pointers (maybe event smart ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ array's size must be determined at the compile time, which means it has to be a constant number.

If size is unknown at the compile time, use std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

For arrays of variable size, use std::vector instead.

Refer:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/